# Bonded interface with interfaces from separate VLANs in Linux

Tags: linux, routing, subnet, network-interface, bonding

If I have two interfaces (`eth0` and `eth1`) on separate VLANs (100 and 200), can they be bonded together into `bond0` in such a way that traffic for each VLAN can be routed correctly?

Let’s say the subnet `10.1.1.0/24` is on VLAN 100 and subnet `10.1.2.0/24` is on VLAN 200 and the gateways are `10.1.1.1` and `10.1.2.1,` respectively.

- **Server 1**: Has `eth0` (VLAN100) and `eth1` (VLAN200). `eth0` has IP `10.1.1.2`, and `eth1` has IP 10.1.2.2.
- **Server 2**: Has `eth0` (VLAN100) and `eth1` (VLAN200). `eth0` has IP `10.1.1.3`, and `eth1` has no IP.

Can `eth0` and `eth1` on server 1 be bonded into `bond0` such that traffic for the `10.1.1.0/24` subnet will flow through `eth0`, and for `10.1.2.0/24` will flow through `eth1`?

Can `eth0` and `eth1` in server 2 be bonded into `bond0` such that it can reach IPs in the `10.1.2.0/24` subnet, even though it doesn't have an IP in that subnet/VLAN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can eth0 and eth1 on server 1 be bonded into bond0 such that traffic for the 10.1.1.0/24 subnet will flow through eth0, and for 10.1.2.0/24 will flow through eth1?

No, **the whole point** of bonding is to make both ports act as a single, unified connection (usually to multiply the available bandwidth). If your interfaces must remain on different VLANs and on different IP subnets, then bonding is the completely wrong tool.

To keep the interfaces separate, you just *keep them separate,* that's all.

---

> Can eth0 and eth1 in server 2 be bonded into bond0 such that it can reach IPs in the 10.1.2.0/24 subnet, even though it doesn't have an IP in that subnet/VLAN?

As already mentioned above, that's not what "bonding" does.

The server *can* be configured to reach the 10.1.2.0/24 subnet, but if it's not directly connected to that subnet, then it uses a *router* to do so. What you're asking for is just **regular IP routing** between networks.

If both subnets share the same gateway, then all neccessary routes should already be present. Just make sure the router's firewall is not configured to block such connections.

If each subnet uses a different device as its gateway, then add static routes on each gateway pointing to the opposite subnet.

Finally, VLAN membership without an IP address is useless. (Same as with physical networks.) If you want a server to be directly connected to multiple networks, then every interface needs an IP address. If you want the server to only have one IP address, then don't create the extra VLAN interfaces at all.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  This helps a lot.